# How should I fix "Expected 0 arguments but found 3" error if I want to use Lombok RequiredArgsConstructor annotation?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I am using Spring, JPA, Java17, MySQL.
IDE: IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.4
JDK: Amazon Coretto 17.0.6

I am getting an error "Expected 0 arguments but found 3". (image)

[image]

Here is my Article entity class code and I am using Lombok to remove boilerplate code. For some reason RequiredArgsConstructor annotation cannot be well managed in test class and I need to create actual constructor to be able to work on it.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "article", schema = "chitchat")
public class Article {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String title;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    @Column(name = "comment_count", nullable = false)
    private int commentCount;

    @Column(name = "view_count", nullable = false)
    private int viewCount;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "article", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Tag> tags = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @Column(name = "modification_date")
    private LocalDateTime modificationDate;

    @Column(name = "creation_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;

    @Column(name = "content", nullable = false, length = 50000)
    private String content;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", nullable = false)
    private User author;

    @Column(name = "published", nullable = false)
    private Boolean published = false;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "article")
    private Set<Comment> comments = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

I tried using AllArgsConstructor and creating constructor by hand (works fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [docs](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/RequiredArgsConstructor) of `@RequiredArgsConstructor` suggests:

> Generates a constructor with required arguments. Required arguments
> are final fields and fields with constraints such as @NonNull.

So, your class does not have fields that match those criteria

Whereas [`@AllArgsConstructor`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/AllArgsConstructor) :

> Generates an all-args constructor. An all-args constructor requires
> one argument for every field in the class.

So, everything works as expected.

Comment: So changing my fields to final and adding @NonNull annotation should solve my problem?

Comment: you haven't specified what you want to achieve, which fields should present in your constructor depends on your business requirements. What I can say, specifying all the fields in constructor of entity class - is really bad idea. You should choose by yourself which fields you want to place into constructor, so, in your case you don't need to use lombok for generating constructor at all, except, for example, @NoArgsConsctructor, since you need it because your class is entity class.

Comment: Alright, thank you. 
It is working now just fine, and I will apply your advice in code.